# Firebug problem in 64 bit Ubuntu distribution

Tags: firefox, 64-bit

I know that Firebug does not run on 64 bit Ubuntu distribution. Do you know some solution for this problem or why it happens?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 64 bit and Firebug runs fine on Firefox. Can  you add some screenshots to show your problem?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu 10.10?

Comment: Yes I am using Ubuntu 10.10. My Firefox version is 3.6.12

Comment: As I remember it was Ubuntu 9.04. Maybe it was a bug. I asked this question because firebug is only reason that stops me to switch on 64 bit, but not any more. Thanks Chakra :)

Comment: Your welcome.. I know how awesome firebug was when I used it for the first time. Aside from this topic you may also try developer tools in Chromium if you havn't by now :)

Comment: I know that Chromium is much more faster, but for me firebug is more comfortable... Is Chromium comfortable for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebug plugin works fine in Ubuntu 10.10 64 bit.
I am using it without any issues on Firefox 3.6.12.

Answer (score 2):

I used to have this problem for a while on lucid. There was also a bug submitted to firebug (firefox crashed with firebug installed). Going to a newer version of firefox/firebug solved the problem at the time.

I had no problems so far with firebug on amd64 using Maverick (10.10).

Maybe you need to be more specific what the exact issue is, if this will not help.